# get request with vanilla javascript and express js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, get

I am trying to practice making a get request with vanilla javascript to express server, but I am stuck in receiving the request in express js (my terminal does not print anything in my get request call).
Am I missing something that my express did not listen to my get request at all?

front end:

```js
    (function () {
      var retrieve = document.getElementById('retrieve'),
        results = document.getElementById('results');
        retrieve.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
          var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
          console.log('GET', e.target.dataset.url);

          oReq.open('GET', e.target.dataset.url, true);
          oReq.onload = function () {
            console.log('Inside the onload event');
            if(oReq.readyState === 4){
              if(oReq.status === 200){
                console.log(oReq.reponseText, "pass");
              }
              else{
                console.error(oReq.statusText);
              }
            }
          };
          oReq.onerror = function(e){
            console.error(oReq.statusText, "error");
          }
          oReq.send(null);
        });
      }());
```

```html
 <h1>Vanilla Ajax without jQuery</h1>
  <button id="retrieve" data-url="/">Retrieve</button>
   <p id="results"></p>
```

express code:

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require("path");
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var morgan = require('morgan');
var db = require('./db');
var cors = require("cors");

var app = express();
app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use('/', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../client')));
app.get("/", function(req,res){
  console.log("get");
});

app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!')
})
```

Comment: where is the html coming from? I cannot see that that it is returned by the express server. Are the html-file and the server on the same domain AND same port?

Comment: Are you sure that the relative url `/` resolves to the correct domain and port? did you check that?